# How to map a SolrNet Query result to a class?

Tags: .net, solrnet

I am trying to query Solr using the SolrNet client.
I can index documents and search for them with the Solr web admin with out error.
When I try to query using the same class I indexed the documents with I get an error like the following on every field.

Error:

Could not convert value 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to property 'Title' of document type Search.WebService.Handler.Document

Why is Solr trying to map an arraylist to each field?
Here are the details of my setup, the schema is based on the example schema.

My Schema:

```
<field name="ReferenceId" type="identifier" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="Title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="Revision" type="identifier" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="Author" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="Filename" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

My Document class:

```
class Document
{
    [SolrField("ReferenceId")]
    public string ReferenceId { get; set; }

    [SolrField("Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [SolrField("Revision")]
    public string Revision { get; set; }

    [SolrField("Author")]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [SolrField("Filename")]
    public string Filename { get; set; }
}
```

An example query:

```
string queryString = String.Format("Title :\"{0}\"", titleSearchTerm);
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery(queryString);
SolrQueryResults<Document> results = index.Query(query);
```

Comment: Consider posting to the SolrNet mailing list instead: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/solrnet . Due to repeated censorship by Stackoverflow moderators, I won't be answering question here any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the attribute multiValued="false" to each of the fields.

More details on [multiValued fields](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml) is found in the documentation.